# Android DatePicker is not appearing on DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make the date picker appear in a dialog fragment upon clicking the date field to write/set the date I selected with the use of the DatePicker. Unfortunately, each time I click, the DatePicker doesn't show up.

Below is the the code of the class:

```
public class UpdateGrade extends DialogFragment{

        private EditText dateField;

        static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),  mDateSetListener,  cyear, cmonth, cday);
            }
            return null;
        }
        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date_selected =String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+"-"+String.valueOf(year);
                dateField.setText(date_selected);
            }
        };

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_grade_layout, container);
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(STYLE_NO_TITLE);
            dateField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dateField);

            dateField.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){ 

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if(v == dateField)
                            getActivity().showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                        return false;     
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the [`onCreateDialog()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog%28android.os.Bundle%29) method to return an instance of [`DatePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html):

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).